# TypeError: a bytes-like

Tags: python-3.x

i help fpr code net shell
sys_drive = []

def system_drive():

```
drive = ["A:","B:","C:","D:","E:","F:","G:","H:","Z:","N:","K:","L:","X:","P:","U:","J:","S:","R:","W:","Q:","T:","Y:","I:","O:","V:","M:"]

cmd = check_output("net share",shell=True).decode("utf-8")

for i in drive:

    if i in cmd:
            sys_drive.append(i)
            
return sys_drive
```

system_drive()

Comment: What's the problem ?

Comment: Code fence is wrong.